# I can't make MuiTelInput work with react-hook-form library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css, react-hook-form

I was trying to make an input for a registration form, which should contain a phone number. I found library from material UI which supports telephone number input. I created it and tried to register it with react-hook-form for dynamic errors and input handling like this:

```
<MuiTelInput
    name="phone"
    className="w-full"
    label="Phone number"
    {...register("phone", {
        required: "Please enter your phone number!",
        minLength: {
            value: 10,
            message: "Phone must be made out of at least 10 characters",
        },
        maxLength: {
            value: 20,
            message: "Phone can not be longer than 20 characters",
        },
    })}
/>
```

The input shows up, and it looks good, but whenever I try to enter something it instantly deletes entered character. Also throws an error in dev-tools:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
at onChange ...
```

Also I want this form to have a default initial value for a country flag to show up (with ability to change it). If you can come up with any ideas that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`MuiTelInput` component does not support the `register` function from `react-hook-form`.
To fix this problem, you need to use the `Controller` component from `react-hook-form`.

For example:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm();

<Controller
  name="phone"
  control={control}
  rules={{
    required: "Please enter your phone number!",
    minLength: {
      value: 10,
      message: "Phone must be made out of at least 10 characters",
    },
    maxLength: {
      value: 20,
      message: "Phone can not be longer than 20 characters",
    },
  }}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
    <MuiTelInput
      label="Phone number"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      error={!!error}
      helperText={error ? error.message : null}
    />
  )}
/>;
```